# return em Promise

Tags: javascript, promises

Olá tenho uma função que tras o ip no httpbin, contudo é uma promise e não consigo colocar o resultado em um return, só quando é executado com console.log outro modo direto:

Funciana assim...

```
async function apiIP() {
              try {
                const resposta = await fetch("http://httpbin.org/ip")
                const dados = await resposta.json()

                console.log dados.origin
              } catch(e) {
                // statements
                console.log(e);
              }

    }
```

mas assim não funciona, quando utilizo o return...

```
async function apiIP() {
              try {
                const resposta = await fetch("http://httpbin.org/ip")
                const dados = await resposta.json()

                return dados.origin
              } catch(e) {
                // statements
                console.log(e);
              }

    }
```

Comment: Mas está tudo certo. Você está usando `await` para capturar o retorno de `apiIP`?

Answer (score 4):

Como você está fazendo uso de [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), você precisa encadear um [`then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) para acessar o valor resolvido pela promise e um [`catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) para realizar a tratativa de erros.

Você pode fazer algo mais ou menos assim:

```js
// Note que estamos uma função assíncrona. Logo, todo valor que
// for retornado por ela será "encapsulado" por uma Promise.
async function getIp() {
  const body = await fetch('https://httpbin.org/ip');
  const data = await body.json();
  
  // O valor retornado será algo como `Promise<object>`.
  return data
}

getIp()
  .then((resolvedJson) => {
    console.log(resolvedJson.origin);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Opa! Houve um erro:', error.message);
  });
```

Uma outra alternativa é fazer o uso do `async`/`await` para consumir uma outra função assíncrona:

```js
async function getIp() {
  const body = await fetch('https://httpbin.org/ip');
  const data = await body.json();
  
  return data
}

async function main() {
  try {
    const resolvedJson = await getIp();
    console.log(resolvedJson.origin);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Opa! Houve um erro:', error.message);
  }
}

main();
```

---

É importante também entender que, para acessar o valor de uma função que retorna uma `Promise`, deve-se encadear um `then` ou usá-la dentro de uma função assíncrona já que, se isso não for feito, estaremos interagindo diretamente com a `Promise`, e não com o seu valor resolvido. Um exemplo desse comportamento:

```js
// A função abaixo retorna uma Promise que resolve após 500ms.
function getMessage() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('Hello, world!'), 500);
  });
}

// Tentando interagir diretamente:
console.log(getMessage());

// Interagindo usando `then` (o que aguarda a resolução da Promise:
getMessage()
  .then((message) => console.log('Usando then:', message));
  
// Interagindo através de uma função assíncrona (o que aguarda a resolução da Promise:
async function main() {
  console.log('Async/await:', await getMessage());
}
main();
```

---

> **Nota:**
>
> É sempre muito importante que você realize a devida tratativa de erros quando se utiliza Promises. Seja através do `try`/`catch` dentro de uma função assíncrona ou o `catch` encadeado em uma função que retorna uma `Promise`.